# Solve Triple Integral by Switching integration Order

Tags: calculus

$$
\iiint_E \mathrm{e}^{z/y}\,\mathrm{d}V \qquad \text{for} \qquad
E = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\le x\le1, y\le x\le 1, 0\le z \le xy\le1\right\}
$$

The triple integral is easily seen to be $\mathrm{e}/2 - 7/6$ using $\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$.

However, if the order of integration is changed to dxdzdy the problem becomes much more difficult and I cannot find the limits. A CalcPlot3D appears to show the shadow in the zy plane as running from z=y^2 to z=y and x appears to run from y to 1 but these give the wrong answer. Could x be represented as z/y?

Comment: One problem is that the condition "y< x< 10< z< xy< 1" is impossible!  If "0< x< 1" then xy< y.

Comment: Sorry. It should be y<x<1, 0<z<xy<1.  a comma was left out. Also, the less than symbols should be less than or equal to.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment we have

$$E = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid 0 \le x\le 1, y\le x\le 1, 0\le z\le xy \le 1\right\}$$

This can be simplified to

$$E = \left\{(x,y,z)\mid 0 \le y\le x\le 1, 0\le z \le xy \right\}$$

Consider that the last condition implies $$0 \le z \le y$$ but then $x$ has to be chosen as $x \ge \frac{z}{y}$ as well as still $x \ge y$ so in total we get $$x \ge \max\left\{\frac{z}{y},y\right\}$$

With $$\max\left\{\frac{z}{y},y\right\} = \frac{z}{y} \;\iff\; z \ge y^2$$ resp. $$\max\left\{\frac{z}{y},y\right\} = y \;\iff\; z \le y^2$$ we get:

\begin{align*}\iiint_E \mathrm{e}^{z/y}\,\mathrm{d}V &= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \int_{\max\left\{\frac{z}{y},y\right\}}^1 \mathrm{e}^{z/y} \;dx\;dz\;dy \\ &= \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} \int_y^1 \mathrm{e}^{z/y} \;dx\;dz\;dy + \int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^y \int_\frac{z}{y}^1 \mathrm{e}^{z/y} \;dx\;dz\;dy\\ &= \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^2} \mathrm{e}^{z/y}(1-y)\;dz\;dy +  \int_0^1 \int_{y^2} ^y \mathrm{e}^{z/y}(1-\frac{z}{y})\;dz\;dy \\ &= \int_0^1 y(1-y)(\mathrm{e}^y - 1)\;dy + \int_0^1 y\mathrm{e}^y(y-2)+\mathrm{e}y \;dy \\&=\left(\frac{17}{6} - e\right) + \left(\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{e} - 4\right) \\ &= \frac{\mathrm{e}}{2} - \frac{7}{6}\end{align*}

Comment: Brilliant Gono.  Your statement "Consider that the last condition implies 0<=z<=y" is not completely clear to me.  Would it be sufficient to say that 0<=z<=xy implies (dividing by y) that z/y<=x. Then the two results below z>=y^2 and z<=y^2 follow from z/y>=y and z/y<=y.

Comment: Let's make it slow: You have $$0 \le z \le xy$$ which gives (dividing by $y$) $$0 \le \frac{z}{y} \le x$$ or vice versa $$x \ge \frac{z}{y}$$ together with $$y \le x \le 1$$ we get $$1 \ge x \ge \max\left\{\frac{z}{y}, y\right\}$$ But unfortunately this is only the range for $x$. The range for $y$ is pretty clearly $$0 \le y \le 1$$ but we still don't have a range for $z$. 
For $z$ we have $$0 \le z \le xy$$ given because you want to have $dx\;dz\;dy$ as integration order we define the range of $y$ BEFORE but the range of $x$ afterwards. So while considering $$0 \le z \le xy$$ the $y$ is…

Comment: …already fixed but the $x$ is not so we have to check what's the maximal range $z$ can take depending on the range of $x$? The range of $x$ is limited by $1$ due to $0 \le x \le 1$ so as the maximal range of $z$ we get $$0 \le z \le \sup_x xy = y$$ hence $$0 \le z \le y$$

Comment: Yes. I see that 0 < z < y represents the overall limits on z, consisting of 0 to y^2 and then y^2 to y.  That was the point. Thank you Gono.